# After adding @media not print in css styles they're not working in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I had a class

```
.content {
    margin-left: 110px;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    -ms-flex-negative: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Which was working fine across all browsers. But after changing it to

```
@media not print {
.content {
    margin-left: 110px;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    -ms-flex-negative: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}}
```

```html
<div class"wrapper"> 
<div class"navigation"> </div>
<div class"content"> </div>
</div>
```

it doesn't work on IE. Shouldn't @media work in IE?

Comment: add your sample html code

Comment: On Which Windows Version you are testing it?

Comment: Windows 10, IE 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In @media print, add `display: none !important;` for your `.content` it will work for all browsers.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 110px;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    -ms-flex-negative: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}

@media print {
    .content,
    .content * {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="navigation"> </div>
    <div class="content">In @media print, add display: none !important; it will work.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It's Working fine! I'm Using Windows 10 and ie11. I found no difference between your codes, maybe that puzzled you! for clearity, I added some extra code, `background: red;`. `@media not print{}` showing the background but the print screen is not. So it's working!

```css
.content {
            margin-left: 110px;
            -ms-flex-positive: 1;
            flex-grow: 1;
            flex-shrink: 1;
            -ms-flex-negative: 1;
            flex-basis: 0;
            position: relative;
            width: 50%;
        }

        @media not print {
            .content {
                margin-left: 110px;
                -ms-flex-positive: 1;
                flex-grow: 1;
                flex-shrink: 1;
                -ms-flex-negative: 1;
                flex-basis: 0;
                position: relative;
                width: 50%;
                background: red; /*added for testing the code*/
            }
        }
```

```html
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: But I only left the code with `@media not print {...` shouldn't itwork without .content class above it?

Comment: Yes! `@media not print{}` means it should work on all media's except the print media.

Comment: What actually you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You did not put '=' while assigning the class name.

[image]

It should be like below.

```
<div class="wrapper"> This is wrapper
<div class="navigation"> This is navigation</div>
<div class="content">This is content </div>
```

I tested the code with Windows 10 , IE 11 version and it is working as expected.

Try to correct your code and let us know about the results.